# Recursion with arguments method

Tags: javascript, recursion, parameters, arguments

The script must have to print 'Hello', then 'Good bye', because of the entries on function call. But only prints once. Why?
What's wrong here bellow.

**PD:** Now it doesn't work. It does if i comment the recursion call line

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function writing(i,first,second) { 
        len=arguments.length;
        if (i<=len) {
            current=arguments[i];
            c=0;
            inter=setInterval(function() {
                    if (c>=current.length) {
                        clearInterval(inter);
                    } else {
                        field=document.getElementById('div1');
                        field.innerHTML+=current[c];
                        c+=1;
                    }
                },200);
        } 
        i<len?writing(i+1,first,second):writing(i=0,first,second);          
     }
    writing(1,'Hello','Good bye');
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Holy missing `var` declarations, Batman!  Omitting the `var` (or `let` or `const`) keyword will cause the variable to be declared at the global scope (`window` in this case)-- causing all sorts of potential naming pollution and crosstalk.  Best to get in the habit of using a linter to help you catch that sort of thing.

Comment: Ok. I've decrease the problem. Now it print an random message with `Undefined`, `Hello` or `Goodbye`. Unrespecting the setInterval time to run by character Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many problems with the code , first was it was infinite loop (never ending) ,  second was variable declaration , and others...

Here I have attached the snippet , please run and check, if its that you are looking for.

I have to add setTimeout for fullfill your requirement.

```js
var interval_counter = 0;

function writing(i, first, second) {
    var len = arguments.length;
    if (i != 0 && i <= len) {
        var current = arguments[i];
        var c = 0;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var inter = setInterval(function() {
                if (c >= current.length) {
                    clearInterval(inter);
                } else {

                    field = document.getElementById('div1');
                    field.innerHTML += current[c];
                    c += 1;
                }
            }, 200);
        }, 200 * interval_counter);
        interval_counter = interval_counter + current.length;
        i < (len - 1) ? writing(i + 1, first, second) : writing(i = 0, first, second);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
writing(1, 'Hello', 'Good bye');
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Right that. Thanks. I really must have to research javascript fundamentals deeper.